# Deleting Products with Magmi Datapump

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

I can successfully delete products with MAGMI's web frontend.
But when using the datapump API, it just seems to ignore the **magmi:delete** column...

```
$this->magmi = Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");
$this->magmi->beginImportSession("Default","create", new MagmiLogger($this));
$prods = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$count = $prods->getSize();
$i = 0;
foreach ($prods as $_p) {
    $this->magmi->ingest(array(
        'sku' => $_p->getSku(),
        'magmi:delete' => '1'
    ));
}
$this->magmi->endImportSession();
```

With this code I try to delete my whole catalog. When executing, the foreach loop runs through without any exception or error by MAGMI. The Product Deleter plugin is activated in my selected Default profile.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I selected the wrong profile...
It works with the posted code, when you really select a profile with activated **"Product Deleter"** plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Click Here to add MAGMI into your module** -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351175

**Enable Product Deleter plugin.**

[image]

> **Using CSV**

```
"sku","magmi:delete"
"sku1","1"
"sku2","1"
```

> **Using Code**

```
    $importData = [];
    $configProduct = new \Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump('productimport');
    $importData['sku'] = "your Product SKU";
    $importData['magmi:delete'] = "1";
    $configProduct->beginImportSession("default", "update");
    $run = $configProduct->ingest($importData);
    $configProduct->endImportSession();
```

> Check **catalog_eav_attribute** table in your db . If **is_configurable** column not present then update below code from **getConfigurableOptsFromAsId()** function in this file **.../magmi/plugins/base/itemprocessors/configurables/magmi_configurableprocessor.php**

```
    //$sql .= " JOIN $cea as cea ON cea.attribute_id=ea.attribute_id AND cea.is_global=1 AND cea.is_configurable=1";
    $sql .= " JOIN $cea as cea ON cea.attribute_id=ea.attribute_id AND cea.is_global=1";
} else {
    //$cond .= " AND ea.is_global=1 AND ea.is_configurable=1";
    $cond .= " AND ea.is_global=1";
```

***Note:- magmi:delete :  1 is to delete the product 0 is to not delete the product***